# How to reinstall ubuntu using same partitioning system

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, reinstalling

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 using the instructions [here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html).

I am a novice at the operating system and was trying to set up a VPN using the instructions from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04).

But I messed up mid-way and now I have no idea how to continue or go back. I changed some system files during the process and I couldn't find a way to restore them. Neither do I know which specific ones I changed. However, it has only been 3 days since I installed the OS and I wanted to re-install it so I can get back the default files.

My question is: Will I be able to use the same partitioning system I created the first time for the swap area, root and home space? And if so, how?

Also, if you have any way I can restore the files I changed, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Good lesson here for new user. Edit sys files sparingly and only after backup. Emacs will create a backup file, but I always do manually, 'cp X.conf X.conf.20160717'. If you tack on date, you easily find your changes 'find / -name "*20160717"'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: Yeah, lesson learnt. I will install a backup software as soon as I re-install it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reinstalling Ubuntu with a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042746/reinstalling-ubuntu-with-a-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no user files that you wish to save and considering the fact that this is a recent install --- start over.

After re-loading Ubuntu visit this site: [Partitioning/Home/Moving](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) which will provide guidance so that you can use the same partition system you previously established.

I don't have any advice on restoring the files that were changed. Since things aren't working, starting over may be the best bet.

Prior to changing a file, make a back-up copy of it. As an alternative, copy a line that will be changed and "#" out the original line so that if the modified line does not work, you can restore the original line.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. I have been able to re-install it

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of any wanted personal files before you begin.

Install from iso media such as a USB or DVD.

If you want to use the same partitions, select "something else" when it asks if you want to install ubuntu "along side" your current operating system.

Then, click on the main ubuntu partition (make sure you know which one it is!) and set the "type" as "ext4" (assuming you previously used ext4 which is the default). Then, set the mount point as `/`.

If you used separate partitions for /home etc, set the mount point for each partition as such. The default is to only use one partition with a mount point of `/` and the swap partition will automatically set itself.

Comment: I was having some trouble installing it at first, but I formatted my usb and re-copied the iso. I have been able to succesfully follow the steps and my machine is back to default.Thanks