# Re-installing Ubuntu without affecting Windows partition (dual-boot)

Tags: dual-boot, reinstall

I want to re-install Ubuntu but I am afraid to start because I am using a dual-boot and don't want to affect my Windows partition.

Has anyone done this before? Tutorials I'm finding is how to reinstall Ubuntu not considering a dual-boot, and tutorials on how to set up a dual-boot, but not in combination.

Any input/known tutorials would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reinstalling Ubuntu with a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042746/reinstalling-ubuntu-with-a-dual-boot)

Comment: That’s a good link I think. The only thing I’d emphasise is that whenever you do something like this, assume the worst could happen and back everything up very carefully before you begin - even if you have no intention of touching that partition.